# How free variable value is determined within nested closure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, scope, closures

I have created a `nested closure` which looks as below:

```
def incrementer(n):
    def inner(start):
        current = start
        def inc():
            nonlocal current
            current += n
            return current
        return inc
    return inner

fn = incrementer(2)
```

Now, when I print value of `co_freevars` for `fn` I get below output:

```
print(fn.__code__.co_freevars) -> ('n',)
```

My understanding is that it should be `('current', 'n')` because there are `2 free variables`
here.

Why `print(fn.__code__.co_freevars)` is not printing `('current', 'n')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `current` in `inner`, so it's a normal local variable there. `current` is a closure variable in `inc`.

Consider:

```
inner = incrementer(2)
inc = inner(1)

print(inner.__code__.co_freevars)
print(inc.__code__.co_freevars)
```

Output:

```
('n',)
('current', 'n')
```

---

Another example to drive home the point:

```
def outer():
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
    var3 = 3
    var4 = 4
    def middle():
        var1
        var2
        def inner():
            var2
            var4
        return inner
    return middle


middle = outer()
inner = middle()

print(outer.__code__.co_freevars)
print(middle.__code__.co_freevars)
print(inner.__code__.co_freevars)
```

Output:

```
()
('var1', 'var2', 'var4')
('var2', 'var4')
```

first print:

`outer` has no closure variables.

second print:

`var1`, `var2` and `var4` are used in `middle` and come from an outer scope. Yes, `var4` is used in `middle`. In the definition of `inner`, which is defined inside of `middle`.

third print:

`var2` and `var4` are used in `inner` and come from an outer scope.

Comment: In that case, it should not even show `('n',)` because there is no closure variable in `inner`

Comment: @meallhour of course there is :) `current += n` is part of `inner`. Change the line to  `current += 1` and you'll get `('current',)` for `print(inc.__code__.co_freevars)`.

Comment: `current += n` is part of `inc` and not `inner`

Comment: @meallhour you define `inc` in `inner`. See what happens when you use `current += 1`.

Comment: I am still not getting it :)  `inc` is defined in `inner`. so everything free variable within `inc` should be accessible from `inner`. This way, `inner` should have 2 free variables - `('current', 'n')`

Comment: @meallhour I added another example, does it help?

Comment: thanks for all your efforts. is it correct to say that all free variables are determined by python at the time of defining inner functions?

Comment: @meallhour I'd say at the time when the parser looks at the functions without executing them. But I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: thanks it is clear now. the example is much helpful